# Windows Installer dialog minimize button

Tags: wix, wix3

I am developing a windows installer using [WiX 3.0](http://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/44406).

The installer dialog, while installing, if minimized and then again maximized, gets stuck in the top left corner of the screen with very little user interface visible from and no buttons/controls are visible.

Is there any way to disable the minimize button from the installer dialog or is there any way that the click event on the minimize button can be captured and handled?

Comment: Confirmed with wix 3.6.2221: if I minimize the installer while the progress bar is visible, it will automatically restore in a strange way to the top left corner when it goes to the "Finish" screen. You may want to submit this as a [wix bug](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=105970&atid=642714) instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Windows 7 bug, was reported a couple of years ago on the WiX mailing list and comes up repeatedly as new developers find the same bug :)

http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Re-WiX-users-Install-on-Windows-7-minimize-the-installation-wizard-then-only-see-a-slice-of-the-instd-td4430104.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that is not possible. It could be possible that this problem has been fixed with a newer version of WiX. WiX 3.6 RC is available now and might be worth looking into.